# WebLogic and Top Link confusion

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle11g

I'm trying to install Oracle WebLogic Server, then when I look for the generic version,
TopLink comes up!

What is the deal ? I dont need to integrate my server with TopLink, but I have to if I want the generic version!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying the "Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.5) + Coherence + OEPE - Package Installer"

Try the "Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.5) ZIP Distribution" from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html

Comment: You know what mate >? I gave up with weblogic! Because I tried everything I couldn't even install it on the Windows!

Answer (score 2):

Oracle TopLink is an implementation of the Java EE standard for persistence, called "JPA". In fact, the open source version of TopLink is called EcplipseLink, and that is the Reference Implementation for the JPA standard.

Oracle WebLogic uses Oracle TopLink internally to provide its JPA support. For example, Entity EJBs in WebLogic use Toplink for their Object-Relational Mapping (basically, moving the data back and forth from a database to WebLogic). Parts of TopLink are also used for Object-to-XML mapping.

Hope that helps :)

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*